# How to concatenate list and delete entire row if any element is empty in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have below CSV file: I read csv and store each column into different variables(Name,Sub,Idx,Isd):

```
Name Sub  Idx Isd
AAB  YAH  2   7
AB   VF   5
     YHJ  3   4

YAH  HJY  25  23
```

Now I want to store them into tabular form(as original data in csv).Now, I want to store the data only if all the cells have data(no empty cells).

My final output:

```
Name Sub Idx Isd
AAB  YAH 2   7
YAH  HJY 25  23
```

I use the following code:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
columns=defaultdict(list)
with open('inputCSV.csv','r',) as f:
    reader=csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        for(k,v) in row.items():
            columns[k].append(v)
name=columns['Name']
Sub=columns['Sub']
Idx=columns['Idx']
Isd=columns['Isd']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would probably be easier to do just using a standard `csv.reader()` rather than a dictionary reader:

```
import csv

with open('input.csv', 'rb') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    header = next(csv_input)
    csv_output.writerow(header)    # copy the header to the output

    for row in csv_input:
        if len(row) and '' not in row:
            csv_output.writerow(row)
```

This first copies the header from the input CSV to the output CSV. Then for each row, it first checks to make sure it is not an empty row. It then tests the whole row to see if there are any empty values. If there are none, it writes the whole row to the output CSV file.

Giving you an `output.csv` containing:

```
Name,Sub,Idx,Isd
AAB,YAH,2,7
YAH,HJY,25,23
```

Note, this assumes you are using Python 2.x. If Python 3.x is being used, replace this line:

```
with open('input.csv', newline='') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
```

Comment: Glad it worked. Don't forget to click the grey tick under the up/down buttons to accept the answer as the accepted solution.